# Не работает построение маршрута MapKit iOS Qt Objective-C

Tags: qt, ios, objective-c, yandex-maps-api, mapkit

Для построения использую метод requestRoutesWithPoints (YMKDrivingRouter). Должен вернутся результат в лямбда функцию, но она не срабатывает.

```
@interface YandexMapView : YMKMapView
@end

@implementation YandexMapView
YMKDrivingRouter* drivingRouter;
YMKDrivingSession* drivingSession;

- (instancetype)init
{
    drivingRouter = [[YMKDirections sharedInstance] createDrivingRouter];
}

- (void)findRoutes
{
    qDebug() << "findRoutes";
    YMKDrivingDrivingOptions* drivingOptions = [[YMKDrivingDrivingOptions alloc] init];
    YMKDrivingVehicleOptions* vehicleOptions = [[YMKDrivingVehicleOptions alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray<YMKRequestPoint*>* requestPoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    YMKPoint* dstPoint = [YMKPoint pointWithLatitude:59.959194
                                           longitude:30.407094];
    YMKPoint* srcPoint = [YMKPoint pointWithLatitude:55.733330
                                           longitude:37.587649];

    [requestPoints addObject:[YMKRequestPoint requestPointWithPoint:srcPoint type:YMKRequestPointTypeWaypoint pointContext:nil]];
    [requestPoints addObject:[YMKRequestPoint requestPointWithPoint:dstPoint type:YMKRequestPointTypeWaypoint pointContext:nil]];

    drivingSession = [drivingRouter requestRoutesWithPoints:requestPoints
                                             drivingOptions:drivingOptions
                                             vehicleOptions:vehicleOptions
                                               routeHandler:^(NSArray<YMKDrivingRoute*>* routes, NSError* error) {
                                                   qDebug() << "findRoutes res";
                                               }];
    qDebug() << "findRoutes end";
}
@end
```

В консоли вижу только:

```
findRoutes
findRoutes end
```

Qt iOS - 5.15.2. MapKit iOS - 4.3.1-full. Xcode - 14.3

ПС. Похожая схема со связкой MapKit Android Qt работает отлично.